# XLSX appending function return empty workbook in an electron js

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, electron, xlsx

I am trying to build an electron app. A part of this is to take in multiple arrays and covert them into an Excel workbook.

I tried using the XLSX library for this purpose but I have been stuck on it for the past three days. I convert the array into a worksheet and append it to a workbook but the workbook is empty every time.

The snippet below is what I am using. I have a total of 8 arrays which I need to convert into `ws` and then append to a work book. Here I have just mentioned two strings.

```js
const exe = require("XLSX") //in preload process

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("excel", { //in preload process
  desktop: XLSX
})

const exe = excel.desktop; // in renderer process from here on 

const array = [
  ["string"],
  ["string"]
]

var wb = exe.utils.book_new();
var ws = exe.utils.aoa_to_sheet(array)
exe.utils.book_append_sheet(wb, ws, "Sheet1");
console.log(wb)

const file = exe.writeFile(wb, "SheetJSExportAOA.xlsx", {
  type: 'file'
});
```

The worksheet `ws` shows data but no data in workbook `wb`.

I want to get a workbook which I can send to main process and use `fs(writeFile)` to get an output to my system.

If anybody knows anything about it do let me know. I would appreciate any help.